# How to avoid UI being loaded before the data in Angular 2 + PrimeNG?

Tags: angular, observable, primeng

I'm new in Angular 2 and I'm using PrimeNG as well.

Just to ilustrate what's happening I duplicated the tab "Configurações" as you can see on the images.

The two tabs have exactly the same code but the behaviors are different. The first one doesn't have the toggles loaded correctly. The second one works fine.

[image: First Tab]

[image: Second Tab]

My HTML:

```
<p-tabView orientation="left">
    <p-tabPanel header="Administrador">
        <p-growl [value]="msgs"></p-growl>
        <p-dataTable [value]="tblColabAdminList">
            <p-column field="snomatrcompl" header="Matrícula"></p-column>
            <p-column field="nflativo" header="Status" styleClass="col-button">
                <template let-tblColabAdmin="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
                    <p-inputSwitch onLabel="ativo" offLabel="inativo" (click)="selectAdmin(tblColabAdmin)" [(ngModel)]="tblColabAdmin.nflativo"></p-inputSwitch>
                </template>
            </p-column>
        </p-dataTable>
    </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

And it's my TypeScript:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfigService } from './config/configService';
import { TblColabAdmin } from './config/TblColabAdmin';
import { Message } from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/app.config.html',
    selector: 'config-app',
    providers: [ConfigService]
})
export class AppConfig implements OnInit {
    private errorMessage: string;

    tblColabAdminList: TblColabAdmin[];

    msgs: Message[] = [];

    constructor(
        private configService: ConfigService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getConfig();
    }

    getConfig() {
        this.configService.getTblColabAdmin().subscribe(
            tblColabAdminList => this.tblColabAdminList = tblColabAdminList,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
    }

    selectAdmin(tblColabAdmin: TblColabAdmin) {
        this.msgs = [];
        this.msgs.push({ severity: 'info', summary: 'Administrador selecionado', detail: 'Matrícula: ' + tblColabAdmin.snomatrcompl });
    }
}
```

I think that in the first tab the UI is being loaded before the data.

But why is it happening and how to solve that? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what kind of back end you were using, but there is such a thing as Router Data Resolvers that may help https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve Angular University has an example https://angular-university.io/lesson/angular-rxjs-reactive-patterns-implementing-a-router-data-resolver-introducing-typescript-tuple-types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A week later, I finally found a solution. I don't know if it's the best approach but works well:

First, I added `<div id="tab" style="display:none">` to my HTML:

```
<div id="tab" style="display:none">
    <p-tabView orientation="left">
    ...
    </p-tabView>
</div>
```

Second, I added a `setTimeout` in my TypeScript to change `display` value in the `style` after 1 second:

```
...
this.configService.getTblColabAdmin().subscribe(
    tblColabAdminList => this.tblColabAdminList = tblColabAdminList,
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
    () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById("tab").setAttribute("style", "display:true");
        }, 1000);
    }
);
...
```

And that's all. Thanks, God =)

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to `ngAfterViewInit()` in your Angular component.

```
import { Component,AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/app.config.html',
    selector: 'config-app',
})
export class ContentComponent implements AfterViewInit  {

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        ... do stuff here
    }
}
```

If this didn't help you can raise an event in your root component on `ngOnInit()` and listen to it in your component.

```
@Component(selector: 'app-element')
@View(
    templateUrl: 'app_element.html',
)
class AppElement implements OnInit {
     ElementRef elementRef;
     AppElement(this.elementRef);

     void ngOnInit() {
         DOM.dispatchEvent(elementRef.nativeElement, new CustomEvent('angular-ready'));
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer, but the ngAfterViewInit doesn't help. And I'm not sure about how to use dispatchEvent.

Answer (score 0):

not helpful on this post but if u use ngModel for selectButton u should let it null

```
this.http
      .get<any>(AppConstants.BASE_URL_API + "/api/sizes")
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.shoeSizes = response;
        this.shoeSizes.forEach((brand) => this.paymentOptions.push({ name: brand.name, value: brand.id }));
        this.selectedSizes = null
      });
```

html

```
<p-selectButton [options]="brandOptions" [(ngModel)]="selectedBrand" optionLabel="label" (onOptionClick)="calle()" optionValue="value">
      <ng-template let-brand pTemplate="item">
                        <div class="custom-option">
                            <span>{{brand.label}}</span>
                        </div>
      </ng-template>
</p-selectButton>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).